# Chrome notification fills my systray

Tags: chrome, awesome

Under awesome, Chrome notification fills my systray with empty spaces.
[image: systray]

Any idea how to fix it ?

PS: I am sure that it comes from chrome, the pop up on mouse over is "Chrome - Notifications", if I close Chrome the systray is correct.